# Can I get the image as a variable for a condition in gitLab CI

Tags: docker, if-statement, gitlab-ci

I have a product and many projects in different versions and a global gitlab-ci.yml that is just linked. Some projects are build with an old Java version (image is overwritten) and some with the new one. Depending on which version is used I would like to add a build parameter using a rule.

Is there a way to query the used image or will I have to use a variable and set the image according to that variable (which would mean I have to update a lot of repositories)

I tried to treat image as a variable but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [`CI_JOB_IMAGE`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) work for you?

Comment: Thank you - that would also do the trick. I've honestly forgotten about asking the question here as I have handed over the responsibility since then.